# how to change single post link

Tags: menus, permalinks, single, frontpage

I have made a website for a client which involves products tab in navigation. Products are the posts that being posted in "posts". I have a front-page.php which is static. posts are displayed in products page.

For e.g. if the site is xyz.com. Than products will be xyz.com/products displaying list of all the products. Products page displays product A, product B etc.

> If I click on product A, it shows xyz.com/product-a. But what i want
>   is xyz.com/products/product-a.

How can i obtain this?

**edited**

However this problem can be solved by changing the permalink structure of postname to product/%postnme%/. But then problem will be what if there are 2 pages displaying the 2 different sets of products? then permalink solution is not work since it is static.

To be more precise:

For e.g product-a, product-b will be displayed in productsA page. product-c, product-d will be displayed in productsB page(xyz.com/productB/). Now when i click on product-c the permalink should be xyz.com/productB/product-c/ and is i click on product-a then permalink should display xyz.com/productA/product-a/. But permalink solution will display both the links as xyz.com/product/product-a and xyz.com/product/product-b..

**Hence this solution will fail**

Comment: Just create a category named `products`, and add the product-a  to it.

Comment: Create product category "products" and create page with same name. then you can fetch all products in "products" page and URL will be as per your need.

Comment: No I am talking about displaying the single product. I have even tried your solution.

Answer (score 0):

On the WP Dashboard, navigate to:

```
Posts => Categories
```

Create new Category, name it - `Products`. Then go to your post/product-a, on the right panel search for categories and add the new category `Products` to the post/product.

Save it or Update the post, refresh the page, now if you check the url for this post, will be something like: `xyz.com/products/product-a`.

[image]

Comment: thanks. I did exactly what you said but it didn't help. I am using wordpress 4.3.1.

Comment: I think it's pretty much the same deal @Gautam-Toraskar